# How do affixes work in Diablo 2?

Tags: diablo-ii

When you are looking for Magic or Rare items. What are the things you need to consider? What affixes can an item get? On what things does it depend? Character level, item level, quality of the item, ...?

I know the most rares worth picking up, but I want to know a way to find out exactly how to see. For example: rare gloves are worth picking up, because they can get 2+ Java and 20% ias. But even here: do I only pick up specific types of gloves: like vampirebone gloves, or do I only pick up elite gloves? How to prove what gloves are worth picking up.

I ve checked out affix calculators, but its getting a bit complicated. They talk about affixlevels, qlevels, tressure classes and so on. I didnt understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All items can have the affixes you want provided that their [ilvl](https://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Item_level) is high enough to hold that affix.

In your specific example, the Spearmaiden's affix (a +2 to javelin and spear skills prefix) can appear on Gloves and Spears above an ilvl of 40 regardless of type of glove/spear.  Alacrity (a 20% Increased Attack Speed suffix) requires gloves with an ilvl of 43.  So what you want to do is be in an area with a minimum lvl of 43 (generally end of a1 nightmare and on) to ensure all the rare gloves in that area has a chance of dropping with those 2 modifiers.

You typically want to pick up all the gloves, but you may not want to wear some of the ones that have high str requirements depending on your build.

Magic items can have at most 1 prefix + 1 suffix, rares can have up to 3 prefixes and 3 suffixes.

One last thing, there are some suffix/prefix mods that can only appear on magic items.  For example, a pair of magic gloves can roll with the Lancer's prefix (+3 javelin) instead of +2.

Comment: Ty for your answer. How did you get the specific information? I want to be able to choose an item like necro heads for example and see the best theoretical combination of affixes/prefixes on that. Is there some website you can do that?

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer you can find the level and item information here: https://diablo.gamepedia.com/Affixes_(Diablo_II)

Comment: To address some other parts of the question: Treasure classes or loot class is the class that an enemy is assigned. Depending on the treasure class of the enemy, they have a certain drop table of items they can drop. For instance, if you're farming for a specific item, there are certain areas and enemies you should be killing for the best chance of that item to drop. There are diablo 2 treasure calculators out there that will tell you specific info about those.

Comment: @lI One last thing: I am wondering about the number of affixes that can spawn on an item. According to D2 Wiki there can be 2-6 affixes on rare items (max number of prefixes/suffixes is 3). So for example a ring can have 6 affixes, gloves can have 6 affixes and boots can have them. The thing that makes rare desirable that there can be "better" affixes on circlets, than say on boots. Am I correct with that? And does the number of affixes depend purely on item level, luck or something else?

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer that's right, different equipment can have unique affixes that can only spawn on those type of equipment.  Circlets, for example can spawn with + skills while boots cannot.  As for the number of affixes, its randomized i believe, as long as there are enough different affixes to pick from, you can have up to 6 on rares.